# How to get the characters following the keyword from a string (python)?

Tags: python, string, text

There is a text, for example:

> [20:00] User: Error [21:00] User: Auth [21:30] User: Params: first second [22:00] User: ErrorNow

I need to get the "first second" from it, which always come after params. I get the text as a string, it can have several params, I only need the last one in the list.

While the working version looks like this:

```
par_ind = text.rfind('Params')
text[par_ind:par_ind+13]
```

But the main disadvantage is that the number of params may change.
Tell me a more convenient solution. I was thinking about converting a string into a dictionary, but it seemed like a stupid idea. What else can I look at?

UPD:
The full text may look like this:

> [20:00] User: Error [21:00] User: Auth [21:30] User: Params: first second [22:00] User: ErrorNow [20:00] User: Error [21:00] User: Auth [21:30] User: Params: first third [22:00] User: ErrorNow [20:00] User: Error [21:00] User: Auth [21:30] User: Params: first fourth [22:00] User: ErrorNow [20:00] User: Error [21:00] User: Auth [21:30] User: Params: first fifth [22:00] User: ErrorNow

I need the last "Params" in the list, in this case "first fifth"

Comment: Assuming you can't change the input string to be a more convenient format, I would probably use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it can have several params"? Can you show an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good time to use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = """[20:00] User: Error [21:00] User: Auth [21:30] User: Params: first second [22:00] User: ErrorNow"""
>>> match = re.search(r'Params: (?P<params>[^[]+)\[\d', text)
>>> match.group('params')
'first second '
```

(You may want to strip the trailing space: `match.group('params').strip()` can work, or adjust the regular expression accordingly.)

Comment: Is it possible to search in the opposite direction? From right to left to get the last result in a row?

Comment: Of course I can use _re.findall(r'params: (?P<params>[^[]+)\[\d', text)[-1]_

Comment: `re.findall(...)[-1]` is probably the easiest. An alternative is to require *not* having the string `Params: ` anywhere after the group, with a negative lookahead.